# Would anyone tell me how to fetch the media:thumb element's attribute from a json feed?

Tags: javascript, json, feed

I made a yahoo pipe that pulls up the atoms as json format; however, I can fetch and display all the elements in my html page except for the  element's attribute.

Would anyone tell me how to fetch the media:thumb element's attribute from a json feed?

I am pasting the html page's code with javascript. If you save the html page and then view it in browser, you will see that all the necessary elements get output at html page except for the media:thumb as I cannot display the attribute of media:thumb when the feed is formatted as json.

I am also pasting the some portion of the json feed so that you can have an idea what i am talking about.

Please tell me how to retrieve attribute from media:thumb element of a json feed by using plain javascript but no server side code or javascript library.

Thank you.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getFeed(feed){
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=40616620df99780bceb3fe923cecd216&_render=json&_callback=piper';
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
    }
    function piper(feed){
var tmp='';
            for (var i=0; i<feed.value.items.length; i++) {
            tmp+='<a href="'+feed.value.items[i].link+'">';
            tmp+=feed.value.items[i].title+'</a><br>';
            tmp+=feed.value.items[i].author.name+'<br>';
            tmp+=feed.value.items[i].published+'<br><br>';
            if (feed.value.items[i].description) {
                tmp+=feed.value.items[i].description+'<br>';

            }
            tmp+='<hr>';
            }
            document.getElementById('rssLayer').innerHTML=tmp;
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getFeed('http://del.icio.us/rss/popular/javascript')">
    <div id='rssLayer'>bchnbc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Some portion of the json feed that gets generated by yahoo pipe:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</head>
piper({"count":2,"value":{"title":"myPipe","description":"Pipes Output","link":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/pipe.info?_id=f7f4175d493cf1171aecbd3268fea5ee","pubDate":"Fri, 02 Apr 2010 17:59:22 -0700","generator":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/","callback":"piper",


"items":

[{

"rights":"Attribution - Noncommercial - No Derivative Works",
"link":"http:\/\/vodo.net\/mixtape1",
"y:id":{"value":null,"permalink":"true"},
"content":{"content":"We're proud to be releasing this first VODO MIXTAPE. Actual tape might be a thing of the past, but before P2P, mixtapes were the most popular way of sharing popular culture the world had known -- and once called the 'most widely practiced American art form'. We want to resuscitate the spirit of the mixtape for this VODO MIXTAPE series: compilations of our favourite shorts, the weird, the wild and the wonky, all brought together in a temporary and uncomfortable company.","type":"text"},

"author":
{"name":"Various"},
"description":"We're proud to be releasing this first VODO MIXTAPE. Actual tape might be a thing of the past, but before P2P, mixtapes were the
most popular way of sharing popular culture the world had known -- and once called the 'most widely practiced American art form'. We want to resuscitate the spirit
of the mixtape for this VODO MIXTAPE series: compilations of our favourite shorts, the weird, the wild and the wonky, all brought together in a temporary and
uncomfortable company.",
"media:thumbnail":
{
"url":"http:\/\/vodo.net\/\/thumbnails\/Mixtape1.jpg"
},
"published":"2010-03-08-09:20:20 PM",
"format":
{
"audio_bitrate":null,
"width":"608",
"xmlns":"http:\/\/xmlns.transmission.cc\/FileFormat",
"channels":"2",
"samplerate":"44100.0",
"duration":"3092.36",
"height":"352",
"size":"733925376.0",
"framerate":"25.0",
"audio_codec":"mp3",
"video_bitrate":"1898.0",
"video_codec":"XVID",
"pixel_aspect_ratio":"16:9"
},
"y:title":"Mixtape #1: VODO's favourite short films",
"title":"Mixtape #1: VODO's favourite short films",
"id":null,
"pubDate":"2010-03-08-09:20:20 PM",
"y:published":{"hour":"3","timezone":"UTC","second":"0","month":"4","minute":"10","utime":"1270264200","day":"3","day_of_week":"6","year":"2010"
}},


{"rights":"Attribution - Noncommercial - No Derivative Works","link":"http:\/\/vodo.net\/gilbert","y:id":{"value":"cd6584e06ea4ce7fcd34172f4bbd919e295f8680","permalink":"true"},"content":{"content":"A documentary short about Gilbert, the Beacon Hill \"town crier.\" For the last 9 years, since losing his job and becoming homeless, Gilbert has delivered the weather, sports, and breaking headlines from his spot on the Boston Common. Music (used with permission) in this piece is called \"Blue Bicycle\" by Dusseldorf-based pianist \/ composer Volker Bertelmann also known as Hauschka. Artistic Statement: This is the first in a series of profiles of people who I think are interesting, and who I see on almost a daily basis. I don't want to limit the series to people who live \"on the fringe,\" but it would be appropriate to say that most of the people I interview are eclectic, eccentric, and just a little bit unique. The art is in the viewing - but I hope to turn my lens on individuals that don't always color in the lines, whether they can help it or not.","type":"text"},"author":{"name":"Nathaniel Hansen"},"description":"A documentary short about Gilbert, the Beacon Hill \"town crier.\" For the last 9 years, since losing his job and becoming homeless, Gilbert has delivered the weather, sports, and breaking headlines from his spot on the Boston Common. Music (used with permission) in this piece is called \"Blue Bicycle\" by Dusseldorf-based pianist \/ composer Volker Bertelmann also known as Hauschka. Artistic Statement: This is the first in a series of profiles of people who I think are interesting, and who I see on almost a daily basis. I don't want to limit the series to people who live \"on the fringe,\" but it would be appropriate to say that most of the people I interview are eclectic, eccentric, and just a little bit unique. The art is in the viewing - but I hope to turn my lens on individuals that don't always color in the lines, whether they can help it or not.","media:thumbnail":{"url":"http:\/\/vodo.net\/\/thumbnails\/gilbert.jpeg"},"published":"2010-03-03-10:37:05 AM","format":{"audio_bitrate":null,"width":"624","xmlns":"http:\/\/xmlns.transmission.cc\/FileFormat","channels":"2","samplerate":null,"duration":"373.673","height":"352","size":"123321266.0","framerate":null,"audio_codec":"mp3","video_bitrate":null,"video_codec":"XVID","pixel_aspect_ratio":"16:9"},"y:title":"Gilbert","title":"Gilbert","id":"cd6584e06ea4ce7fcd34172f4bbd919e295f8680","pubDate":"2010-03-03-10:37:05 AM","y:published":{"hour":"3","timezone":"UTC","second":"0","month":"4","minute":"10","utime":"1270264200","day":"3","day_of_week":"6","year":"2010"
}}

]
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created the JSON, can't you edit the feed so as to display the elements that you can manipulate using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to traverse XML documents than it is to traverse JSON objects to find particular node type. In XML it will be as simple as xmlDom.getElementsByTagName("media:thumb").

However, in Javascript, I went for the following:

```
function recurseAndFind(obj, key) {
  var x,
      temp,
      current,
      ret = [];

  for (x in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
      current = obj[x];

      if (x == key) {
        ret.push(current);
      } else if (typeof current === "object") {
        temp = recurseAndFind(current, key);

        if (temp.length) {
          ret = ret.concat(temp);
        };
      } else if (typeof current === "array") {
        for (var i=0;i<current.length;i++) {
          temp = recurseAndFind(current[i], key);

          if (temp.length) {
            ret = ret.concat(temp);
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };

  return ret;
};
```

Which is used as follows:

```
var allOccurancesOfMediaThumb = recurseAndFind(items, 'media:thumb');
```

`allOccurancesOfMediaThumb` will be an array of the occurances (or an empty array if none were found).